# Create button download codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, download

In my views I have a file: `contract_list.php`

[buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuBqv.jpg)

```
<td width="1%" class="remove_tag">';
if($this->green->gAction("P"))
{
    $tr .='<a title="Preview Contract" id="clk_pri" class="clk_pri">
    <img rel="'.$contract['con_id'].'" src="'.site_url('../assets/images/icons/preview.png').'" onclick="preview_contract(event);" style="width:20px;height:20px;"></a>';
}$tr .='</td>
```

Function preview when click above Button

```
function preview_contract(event){
            //Code here event click
    }
```

I want download file .pdf .doc form folder ? But name File record in Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user $this->load->helper('download') for codiegniter and force_download($name, $data) and pass your file name at $name variable.

```
public function plaintext() {
        //load the download helper
        $this->load->helper('download');
        //set the textfile's content 
        $data = 'Hello world! Codeigniter rocks!';
        //set the textfile's name
        $name = 'filedownload.txt';
        //use this function to force the session/browser to download the created file
        force_download($name, $data);
    }
```

For full view , you can refer following url

http://code.runnable.com/Uha2YpCDyMQpAAJi/download-file-using-codeigniter